# Reversed Arabic text at dbgrid

Tags: delphi, arabic, dbgrid

I'm have a program that was working fine... after upgrading to rad studio 11+ I'm facing a problem that I can't understand.

BiDiMode:= bdRightToLeft
all tdbgrids at this program working fine except two tdbgrids... the problem is one specific field always shown reversed and separated letters. I deleted the dbgrid and created a new one but the same issue exits.

as you can see the first field showing normally and correctly...

[image]

the same field is reversed here in other dbgrid

[image]

text is reversed and separated in that fields only - other fields in Arabic too and showing correctly.

tried setting BiDiMode:= bdLeftToRight and it's working fine, but when using BiDiMode:= bdRightToLeft the problem appears

I tried tms dbadvgrid (Trial) it's working fine, sorry for my weak English

Comment: You can post to the TMS forums, even while using a trial

Comment: I have no issues with tms, the problem with the TDBGrid

Comment: I tried BiDiMode:= bdLeftToRight and it working fine, but when using BiDiMode:= bdRightToLeft the problem appears